# How to identify which layout is loading at the top most in Recycler view android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am working in a recyclerview which comprises of three different layouts. I coded a common adapter for the three layouts using the getItemViewType() and my recyclerview works fine. Now i want to show the title of the layout(whether 1 or 2) in top as STICKY HEADER.

I added a Textview under frameLayout to act as StickyHeader.

In my adapter, i am setting a static string value as "Layout one" or "Layout two" on getItemViewType method to get the value from activity.

```
public static String title_sticky="";

  @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (items.get(position) instanceof Movie) {
            title_sticky="LAYOUT ONE";
            return MOVIE;
        } else if (items.get(position) instanceof Movie1) {
            title_sticky="LAYOUT TWO";
            return MOVIE1;
        }/*else if (items.get(position) instanceof Blockbuster ) {
            return BLOCKBUSTER ;
        }*/
        return -1;
    }
```

Now in the activity,

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                stickyText.setText(ComplexRecyclerViewAdapter.title_sticky);

            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                    stickyText.setText(ComplexRecyclerViewAdapter.title_sticky);
            }
        });

On addOnscrollListener and onScrolled method of recyclerview, i am just getting the stickystring value from Adapter and setting it to StickyHeaderText.
```

Now, my problem is whenever the second layout's first item is visible at the bottom of my recyclerview upon scrolling, Stickytitle gets changes to 'Layout Two'.

How to identify which layout is loading at the top most in Recycler view so that i can populate my stickyheader value based on that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch the position of the first visible item like so:

```
int firstVisibleItem = ((LinearLayoutManager)recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
```

Now with your `getItemViewType` method retrieve it's type, or implement a method that retrieves the layout identifier like you did for the type

To get the view of the top position you can use:

```
View view =((LinearLayoutManager)recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findViewByPosition(firstVisibleItem);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it returns the position. Is there any way to find which layout is loaded in top?

Comment: I tried your answer, view is giving some values which is not sufficient to differentiate two layouts... I also tried with view.getId() and view.getclass() methods. But they all are returning same values. Any idea on how to acheive this? Two xmls i have , layout_xml_one and layout_xml_two

Comment: Using .setTag() and getTag() i did it

Comment: Glad it helped. Mark the answer as correct since it solved your problem. Happy coding